# PHP strftime borra arreglo

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un arreglo para llenar una tabla con la consulta de una base de datos, al momento de traer las fechas que están guardadas les doy formato en español para pasarlas al arreglo pero no muestra nada.

Este es el php:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT *";
$sql.=" FROM registros where estado = 'pendiente'";
$query=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) or die("ajax-grid-data.php: get PO");
$data = array();
while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES");
    $dir = $row["dir_obra"];
    $time = $row["hora"];
    $fecha = $row["fecha_entrega"];
    $date = new DateTime($time);
    $datef = new DateTime($fecha);
    $hora12 = $date->format("h:i");
    $newfecha = $datef->format('l jS \of F Y');
    $hora= $hora12;
    $fechaf = $newfecha;

    $fecha_entrega = new DateTime($row["fecha_entrega"]);
    //echo strftime("%c", $fecha_entrega->getTimestamp())."<br/>";
    $fecha_entrega_esp = strftime("%a, %d de %B del %G", $fecha_entrega->getTimestamp())."<br/>";
    //echo $fecha_entrega_esp;

    $fechahr = $fechaf." ".$hora;
    $dirind = $dir." ".$row["indicaciones"];

    $nestedData=array(); 

    $nestedData["id"]             = $row["id"];
    $nestedData["cliente"]        = $row["cliente"];
    $nestedData["metodo_pago"]    = $row["metodo_pago"];
    $nestedData["fechahr"]        = strftime("%a, %d de %B del %G", $fecha_entrega->getTimestamp())."<br/>";
    $nestedData["fecha_registro"] = $row["fecha_registro"];
    $nestedData["dir_obra"]       = $dir;
    $nestedData["indicaciones"]   = $row["indicaciones"];
    $nestedData["resistencia"]    = $row["resistencia"];
    $nestedData["pu"]             = $row["pu"];
    $nestedData["tiro"]           = $row["tiro"];
    $nestedData["m3"]             = $row["m3"];
    $nestedData["ton"]            = $row["ton"];
    $nestedData["elem_colar"]     = $row["elem_colar"];
    $nestedData["revenimiento"]   = $row["revenimiento"];
    $nestedData["adicionales"]    = $row["adicionales"];
    $nestedData["padd"]           = $row["padd"];
    $nestedData["responsable"]    = $row["responsable"];
    $nestedData["fecha_entrega"]  = strftime("%a, %d de %B del %G", $fecha_entrega->getTimestamp());
    $nestedData["hora"]           = $hora;
    $nestedData["dirind"]         = $dirind;


    $data[]                       = $nestedData;
}
$json_data = array("data" => $data);
echo json_encode($json_data);
?>
```

Lo más raro es que ayer que lo implementé por primera vez y funcionó pero hoy no, además cuando le agrego cualquier otro formato o variable de fecha funciona a la perfección.

Comment: Hacé un `var_dump()` de esas fechas antes de generar el json, para ver qué está pasando en el medio.

Comment: Este es el resultado:
`object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(22) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(8) ["type"]=> int(0) }`

Comment: el query te trae resultado?

Comment: Si amigo, de hecho incluso hice la prueba solo mostrando la fecha convertida y si funciona, el problema es que cuando intento ponerla en el arreglo no me muestra nada.